# How i can solve the devServer problem in webpack?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would be grateful for any help or advice. I have compiled the configuration of the webpack, everything works in production mode, but the webpack-dev-server does not see static files and gives the error "Cannot get /". How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance for the answer. Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
// const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const isDev = !isProd;

const optimization = () => {
  const config = {
    runtimeChunk: "single",
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          priority: -10,
          chunks: "all",
        },
      },
    },
  };

  if (isProd) {
    config.minimizer = [
      new CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin(),
      new TerserWebpackPlugin(),
    ];
  }

  return config;
};

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  mode: isProd ? "production" : "development",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "[name].[contenthash:8].js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].[contenthash:8].js",
    publicPath: "./",
  },
  devtool: isDev ? "source-map" : false,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?\S*)?$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name][contenthash:8].[ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webm|mp4|svg)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name][contenthash:8].[ext]",
          outputPath: "assets/img",
          esModule: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              esModule: false,
            },
          },
          "css-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contenthash:8].css",
      chunkFilename: "[name].[contenthash:8].css",
    }),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "public", "index.html"),
      filename: "start-page.html",
      alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: isProd,
      },
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: "@vue/runtime-dom",
    },
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".vue", ".json"],
  },
  optimization: optimization(),
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    hot: true,
    client: {
      overlay: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Here is a project folders
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc, you need to set the publicPath in the devServer.

Look at the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
  },
};
```

Comment: TY for your answer. I did it, but devServer see only the index.html file and it doesn't see css and js files(

Comment: sorry, I specified the wrong path to the folder, everything works! Thanks!